# material-ui button with styled-components including react router Link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui, styled-components

I'm working in React with typescript and styled components. I'm also using material-ui library. I've created styled material-ui buttons like below:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {Button, ButtonProps} from "@material-ui/core";
type StyledButtonProps = ButtonProps & { $color?: string, component?: JSX.Element, to?: string }

export const CancelButton = styled(Button)`
  background-color: ${(props: StyledButtonProps) => props.$color ? props.$color : "blue"};
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  padding: 7px 14px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px;

  &:hover {
    background-color: #5e5d5d;
  }

  & .MuiButton-label {
    color: #070303;
  }
` as React.ComponentType<StyledButtonProps>

export const DeleteButton = styled(CancelButton)`
  &:hover {
    background-color: #6c1919;
  }

  & .MuiButton-label {
    color: #070303;
  }
`;
```

I'm trying to use those styled buttons as a **Link**. In material-ui is mentioned about it : https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

For example we can do something like that:

```
<Button component={Link} disabled>
   disabled
 </Button>
```

The problem is when I try to do the same thing with my styled buttons like below:
[image]

Why is that? How Can I solve it? I tried to add additional props:

```
component?: JSX.Element, to?: string
```

but it hasn't helped. Result with or without them is the same.

Minimum reproducible code: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-jqrht

Comment: https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link does this help you? Remember to forwardRef

Comment: I would like to have Link inside material-ui Button.

Comment: @KrzysztofMichalski which material-ui version you are using?

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducable example in react sandbox

Comment: I'm using 4.12.2 version.

Comment: @captain-yossarian - my minimum reproducable example: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-jqrht

Comment: @KrzysztofMichalski please fix syntax errors

Comment: @captain-yossarian - I've just fixed error. Please check my code.

Comment: `component` property does not exists in `CancelButton` component

Comment: Button that has a Link as a component it's like the cup into the coffee. Why don't you make a Link that has a customized button as component?? Just my opinion...

Comment: Hey @KrzysztofMichalski did you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `forwardRef`.

```
const CustomLink = forwardRef(({to,...props}, ref) => {
    return <Link to={to} ref={ref} {...props} />
})

<CancelButton $color="grey" component={CustomLink} to="/about">
          test
</CancelButton>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-pond-jqrht?file=/src/App.tsx

Reference: https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#link

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me. The component prop itself is still unknown for the styled CancelButton.

Answer (score 2):

Struggled with this today.

The solution is to cast the type:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

const CustomButton = styled(Button)({
  // your custom styles go here
}) as typeof Button;
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/#complications-with-the-component-prop