# MUI v5 + styled() + ListItemButton: property 'to'/'component' does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui

In the migration from MUI v4 to v5 I'm hitting this road block: in v4 I've used `makeStyles()`, but now want to fully migrate to `styled()`: I can't get Typescript to accept a `styled(ListItemButton)(...)` with `to=` and `component=` properties.

I've seen and read MUI's guide on [Wrapping components](https://mui.com/guides/composition/) which actually made things even less clear to me; admittedly, I'm neither a Typescript nor MUI wizard. My confusion is fueled by the guide's examples being incomplete, such as obviously lacking some non-obviously imports which seem to need imported symbol renaming, so automatic completion won't work or turn up multiple candidates.

This is a minimized example triggering the Typescript error, see below for codesandbox link.

```js
import React from "react"
import {
  Avatar,
  Link,
  ListItemAvatar,
  ListItemButton,
  styled
} from "@mui/material"

const ListItemButtonLink = styled(ListItemButton)(({ theme }) => ({
  // ...here be styling
}))

interface LinkedListItemProps {
  path: string
}

export const LinkedListItem = ({ path }: LinkedListItemProps) => {
  return (
    <ListItemButtonLink key={42} dense to={path} component={Link}>
      <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar>A</Avatar>
      </ListItemAvatar>
      Here Be Item
    </ListItemButtonLink>
  )
}
```

I'm totally out in the dark in how to get this working, as the Guide example doesn't pass Typescript checking either.

Looking through the MUI issues I found an issue that tackled the Guide issue, but doesn't really seem to fix it in a way that I could use.

I've also seen and read [MUI button with styled-components including react router Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755545/material-ui-button-with-styled-components-including-react-router-link), but the solution is basically the non-Typescript guide version of a kind.

[image: Edit styled-listitembutton] (updated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`Link`](https://mui.com/components/links/#main-content) from the MUI package, this `Link` is just an anchor element but with better style integration with MUI theme, The `Link` you might want to use is from react-router which has a `to` prop, so change your code to:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

If you use `styled` and want the resulted component to have the prop `to` from react-router, you can add the generic type parameter to the HOC:

```
import { Link, LinkProps } from "react-router-dom";

const ListItemButtonLink = styled(ListItemButton)<LinkProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  // ...here be styling
}));
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: I've updated the codesandbox, but it still does not pass Typescript checks. Did I made a mistake?

Comment: @TheDiveO I just updated my answer the moment you submitted the comment, can you try again?

Comment: Yes, what a pair of (erm...) angular brackets can do... Can you please elaborate why the MUI-supplied Link and LinkProps don't work, but React router's original Link and LinkProps do? I would have expected to use the MUI-supplied variants?

Comment: @TheDiveO See my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69458245/9449426) answer, it's a typescript syntax to add generic. MUI `Link` doesn't work because simply it's just a dumb pretty link (you can still pass the `href` attribute), but no integration with react-router, see the type definition of MUI [`Link`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Link/Link.d.ts) (not sure if this explains you well)

Comment: Thank you very much, for both the quick help as well as explaining the underlying mechanics w.r.t. MUI's Link and react-router's Link. Somehow I overlooked that difference and always though that MUI's Link builds upon react-router's when in fact these are two separate pair of shoes, so there's freedom to mix and match.